# JS Add button after tag

Tags: javascript

I have tag `a-av-player` (tag is visible after 3 second) and I need add button on end this tag. I use js:

```
function foo() {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = 'fs-vid-button';
  button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

  // 2. Append somewhere
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("v-av-player")[0];
  body.appendChild(button);
}

setInterval(function() {
  foo()
}, 3000)
```

Script is working only when I change "getElements" to "body" why?
Please help me :)

Comment: You need to show your html

Comment: there is no standard HTML tag named `v-av-player`. Is this an `ID` or `class` attribute value?

Comment: So you actually have a `<v-av-player>` element???

Comment: From your tag name, are you using Vue.js? If so, raw DOM manipulation isn't the way you want to do this... If you aren't, we need to see your HTML.

Comment: Yes <a-av-player>

Comment: Can you post your error code.

Comment: `<a-av-player> !== <v-av-player>`

Comment: It actually works.. assuming its normal HTML + JS. https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/s79y6c8r/

Comment: Btw, you might want to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval `. setInterval works every 3 second, setTimeout works once after 3 seconds.

Comment: I have error "TypeError: body is undefined"

Comment: You said you have a tag `<a-av-player>` however you're looking for an element called `<v-av-player>` which just by looking at this, does not exist. You need to post more code. @Naath

Answer (score 0):

What about having this button with just style="visibility: hidden;"?

You can then access this button and change style document.getElementById("your_button_id").style.visibility = "visible";

Or you may play with classes document.getElementById("your_button_id").classlist.remove("your_class"), so you remove css class, which may be hiding it.

...

or "display: none;" and then "display: block;"

Comment: I cant add button because my tag is auto generate after 3 second